# Filtering Arrays in a Reducer - Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Following a React tutorial, I see this code in a reducer to remove a message from an array using its ID:

[image]
Wouldn't this be better written as:

`else if (action.type === 'DELETE_MESSAGE') {
    return {
      messages: [
        ...state.messages.filter(m => m.id === action.id)
      ],
    };
};`

I thought for a second that `filter` might modify state and return the same array but according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it creates a new array.

Am I safe, and is my implementation correct?

Comment: It appears the spread operator concats both arrays. see https://repl.it/EvXg/1 @Rajesh

Comment: I wonder if there are performance reasons. Could the slice method be faster with a large array?

Comment: @Scimonster That's what I was thinking. I don't understand their approach, it seems deceivingly inefficient.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. It would actually be a very clean solution. The trick is that, in [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), every element of an array is applied with a function that accepts more than one argument. Such a function, when returns a boolean value, is called *predicate*. In case of `Array#filter` (and in fact, some other methods of `Array.prototype`), the second argument is index of the element in source array.

So, given that you know the index, it's simply

```
(state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  messages: state.messages.filter((item, index) => index !== action.index)
})
```

However, you don't know the index. Instead, you have a value of `id` property. In this case, you're right, you simply need to filter the source array against this `id` to only put elements that have value of `id` that is *not equal to* target `id`:

```
(state, action) => ({
  ...state,
  messages: state.messages.filter(item => item.id !== action.id)
})
```

Take a note: no need to spread `state.messages` and put them back into a new array. `Array#filter` doesn't mutate the source array, which is nice.

So, it's `!==` instead of `===`. You were close.